# Elements are moving(they shouldn't be) when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to improve my css(and html) skills by trying to re-create the homepage of reddit.

The problems I have are the sidebars simply won't stay where they are supposed to be when resizing the browser window, they go up and the width is also changing.

The way it is on my end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBfia.jpg (Look at the right side things)

The way it should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdbiM.jpg ( They always stay on the same width and height)

HTML for just the blue bars on the right side which say "Submit a new link"(in the imgur link). I assume if I can get one of them to work I can get all the other elements to work properly too.

```
      <div class="container">
                 <div class="div1">
                       <a href="/">Submit a new link</a>
                 </div>

                 <div class="div2">
                      <a href="/">Submit a new text post</a>
                 </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
          html, body{
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              width: 100%; 
            }

       .container{
              display: block;
              margin-top: 8%;
              margin-left: 87%;
              width: 8%;
          }


        .div1, .div2 {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 5%;
            background: rgb(212, 229, 245);
            height: 100%;
            padding: 7px;
            width: 199%;
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: -53%;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #c4dbf1;
            font-size: 150%;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: -1px;
            font: normal medium verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
           }

     .div1 a, .div2 a{
           font-weight: bold;
           text-decoration: none;
          }
```

I tried so many possibilities, messing with position, display, float, width, margins. This question has been answered a million times but I couldn't find something that helps me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't use percentage width if you don't want the element to change the width on resize. Try setting some width in pixels, like `250px` or something like that

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with media queries? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: @zmuci I have tried doing that, with my current code, that makes it look even worse.

Comment: Set a fixed width for the right side div.